# Join Subquery result Performance

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I'm looking to optimize my SQL query and would like to know, in terms of optimization performance, if

```
SELECT A.this, B.another FROM A
JOIN B 
ON A.this = B.that
WHERE B.another > 6
AND A.something < 3;
```

is better than:

```
SELECT A.this, B.another 
FROM (SELECT this FROM A WHERE A.something < 3) AS A
JOIN (SELECT another FROM B WHERE B.another > 6) AS B
ON A.this = B.that;
```

Comment: Postgres has a pretty smart optimizer, so I don't think that it materializes subqueries.  In other words, the two versions should have similar performance.  But, you should really look at the query plans.

Comment: I would think that that sort of optimisation is best left to the DB, and using the standard syntax of your first query gives the optimiser most scope, but I'm not a DBA. I'll be interested to hear more informed opinions on this.

Comment: What was the result when you tried both of them? That's the only real way to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries will be identical when run. Try running the two queries preceded by `explain analyze`, and you should get the exact same query plan.

In a nutshell, Postgres will parse the query and come up with a query tree.

It'll then rewrite the query tree when appropriate, to remove redundant things such as an `1 = 1` where clause, replacing a small `IN ()` clause or with its equivalent using `ANY`, or, in your case, collapsing your two subqueries into the parent query. The reason it'll do so is that it'll basically view them as `select (select ...)` with the inner select not being subjected to an aggregate, group by or limit clause.

Only then does it spend some time analyzing the query tree itself in search for a query plan it deems sufficiently optimal. And finally execute the query plan to return the rows you've asked for.

For the gory details you'll want to check out the Postgres manual on performance tips, as well as the `explain` and `explain analyze` syntax:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/performance-tips.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/planner-stats-details.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/geqo.html
- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization

Also note the Postgres performance mailing list, whose archives you'll find here:

- http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-performance/

Studying them is well worth the effort, in the sense that doing so will give you a wealth of insights as to what is going on under the hood. Give attention to messages written by Tom Lane in particular -- he occasionally gives a first hand account of what's going on in the query rewriter and planner.